# Objective C, Extract Class @Properties from Array

Tags: objective-c, class, nsmutablearray

I've got a routine that is parsing a video EDL and extracting the event #, Source Start and End Timecodes, and Record Start and End Timecodes. In addition, it is also looking for locators with VFX names. My class "Event" has @Property for each of these elements.

In the following code snippet, I've assigned the elements to an instance of my Event class (*e) and added it to an NSMutableArray (*edl).

```
if ([tempLineElements count] >= 4 && [tempLineElements[0] isEqualToString:@"*LOC:"]) {

    NSMutableString *locatorText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    Event *e = [[Event alloc] init];

    e.edlEvent = tempEvent;
    e.srcStart = tempSrcStart;
    e.srcEnd = tempSrcEnd;
    e.recStart = tempRecStart;
    e.recEnd = tempRecEnd;
    e.markerColor = tempColor;
    e.vfxName = tempVFXName;

    //edl is an NSMutableArray

    [edl addObject:e];
    eventCount++;
}
```

This all works swimmingly, and I have successfully used edl (the MutableArray) as a datasouce for a TableView. Great!

But the problem now is that I have no idea how to extract the @properties back out of MutableArray edl. The array is an ordered list of Event objects. Is this in essence a 2 dimensional array needing two indices? Or do I need to take each entry in my array and somehow populate a new instance of my Event class and extract the details from there?

Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm a, well, newbie. Thanks in advance for any guidance you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a one-dimensional array of `Event` objects.  Finding a property is conceptually the reverse of what you wrote in the question.  In the simple case, you don't need to populate a new instance, just fetch the one that you now have in the array.  For example:

```
// Assuming the array has been populated...
Event *e = [edl objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Name: %@", e.vfxName);
```

This is what you would be doing when you display table data, though using `indexPath.row`, typically, instead of `0` as the array offset.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I was so close, and yet SO FAR. I was definitely overcomplicating it. I was going to post my earlier attempt as a way NOT to do it, but I can't figure out how to block the code in the comments. It's confounded me, and I only had 5 minutes to figure it out before it shut me down. :)